# Alternative overview for structures

Tags: structure, user-interface

Most of our websites use a main structure for the page tree. In some cases, those structures can become quite large and entries further down are not shown initially without scrolling down/autoloading. This is annoying, especially it has to be done again and again when you reopen the structure overview.

For me some changes / additions could improve the situation:

- Have a setting that forces only level 1 entries to be shown, the others are closed.
- Alternatively have a button to close all level 2 and deeper subtrees.
- and maybe remember search terms when leaving the overview and coming back.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Not sure if this is a question or a feature suggestion? Feel free to look for a relevant issue at Craft's [issue tracker](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) or raise a new issue.

Comment: a question: I wanted to find out if others share the same problem and what they think about my ideas. afterwards of course an FR.